# How to pass text from edittext as parameter in XML?

Tags: android, xml, xamarin, soap

I am calling a SOAP web service without using the wsdl and proxy in Xamarin Android. I want to pass username and password from my edittext as a parameter in the XML file.

Here is my code:

```
public void Execute()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
            XmlDocument soapenvelopxml = new XmlDocument();
            soapenvelopxml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:ctrm=""http://CTRMService/CTRM"" xmlns:dtom=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DTOModelLayer.DataContracts"">
            <soapenv:Header>
            <DataHeader xmlns='http://CTRMService/CTRM'>AuthenticateUser</DataHeader>
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soap:Body>
            <ctrm:AuthenticateUser>
            <ctrm:request>
            <dtom:Password></dtom:Password>
            <dtom:Username></dtom:Username>
            </ctrm:request>
            </ctrm:AuthenticateUser>
            </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>");

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapenvelopxml.Save(stream);
             }

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {

                    string soapresult = rd.ReadToEnd();
}
}
}
```

I want to pass the text from my username and password's edittext between the `<dtom:Password>` and `<dtom:Username>` tags.

Comment: Have a look at the String.replace() function.

Comment: Checked that out. Is it possible to pass a variable containing string between those tags?

Comment: Of course. Yes.

Comment: Could you tell me how? I got the text from my usernsme edittext as string usertext =user.text.tostring() now how to pass this usertext variable ?

Comment: Please add a little bit of code that we can see that you try to use the replace function on a string. Then if you have problems we will help. Put all in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: I have no idea about using string.replace method here. That's why i am asking for help!

Comment: Why not here? Place that xml text in a string xml: first. Then use xml.replace(). What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
...
<dtom:Username>@username</dtom:Username>
...

xml = xml.Replace("@username", usertext);

soapenvelopxml.LoadXml(xml);
```

Comment: Haha! You gonna mock me here? :D  i am sorry. Me new in application development so i am trying to learn as much as i can. Bare with me! Thanks :)